# Search result not working after second page of pagination

Tags: codeigniter

i'm beginner in Codeigniter and everything works well , but i have one problem , i made search and that reply with a correct results but i press to the second page i got error , i searched to much and saw a topic talking about session but not working with me

That is my controller

```
public function search(){
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model(array('CustomReport_m','user','Customer_m')); // This array to save number of lines only
        $username=$this->input->post('select_user');
        $total_row = $this->CustomReport_m->search_count($username);
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'CustomReport/search/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if ($this->uri->segment(2)) {
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(2));
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"]= explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
        $data['users']=$this->user->display_users();
        $data['userdata'] = $this->user->userdata();
        $data['customers']= $this->Customer_m->index();
        if(isset($username)and !empty($username)){
              $data["rsl"] =$this->CustomReport_m->search($username,$config["per_page"],$page);
            //$data["rsl"] = $this->CustomReport_m->search($config["per_page"],$page,$username);
            $this->load->view('customreport_v',$data);
        }else{
            redirect('CustomReport','refresh');
        }
    }
```

That is my Model

```
public function search_count($username) {
        $this->db->like('t_u_id',$username);
        return $this->db->count_all("transactions");
    }
    public function search($username,$limit,$start)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
        $this->db->from('transactions');
        $this->db->like('t_u_id',$username);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, I tested it and worked , good luck

```
   public function search(){
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model(array('CustomReport_m','user','Customer_m')); // This array to save number of lines only
        $username=$this->input->post('select_user');
        $username = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : $username;
        $total_row = $this->CustomReport_m->search_count($username);
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['base_url'] = site_url("CustomReport/search/$username");
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if ($this->uri->segment(4)) {
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(4));
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"]= explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);
        $data['users']=$this->user->display_users();
        $data['userdata'] = $this->user->userdata();
        $data['customers']= $this->Customer_m->index();
       if(isset($username)and !empty($username)){
           $this->session->set_flashdata('search',$username);
              $data["rsl"] =$this->CustomReport_m->search($username,$config["per_page"],$page);
            //$data["rsl"] = $this->CustomReport_m->search($config["per_page"],$page,$username);
            $this->load->view('customreport_v',$data);
        }else{
            redirect('CustomReport','refresh');
        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked well , but when i search for a record smaller than 2 , the result 1 row only ! , please anyone help

Answer (score 1):

You missed to put a variable for pagination on controller.

```
public function search($page_num = 1) {
```

And then, instead of checking segment of URI (`if ($this->uri->segment(2))`)
Check the incoming page number.

Because, error occurs on routing time, therefore Codeigniter gives error before executing the 'search' method.

Comment: Not working with me, and when i got result in the first page, i found the link path to second page is`http://localhost/elvan/CustomReport/search/?per_page=5`

Comment: `if ($this->uri->segment(2))` this correct ,
the pagination wokring good in the main page but the problem the pagination lost the search results in the second page